# How to load Divs in Django separately from same or different views?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, django

I have a three pane view where the right pane loads data depending what you click on in center pane.
Right now I just have one view that returns data for all three panes (`None`for right pane, if nothing selected in center pane pane, like when the page is first loaded)

But the problem now is, since every time something on center pane is click on, the page reloads. So all the scroll bars return to top position.

Is there a way to separately load the two panes (HTML divs) on the same page using the same or different views?

TEMPLATE:

```
{% block content %}
{% load guardian_tags %}
{% get_obj_perms request.user for issuelist as "issuelist_perms" %}
<section>
    <div>
        <strong>Currently viewing: </strong><em>{{issuelist.name}}</em>
    </div>
</section>
<section><div id="basepanel" class="auto-style5">
    <div id="panel1" class="auto-style5">
        {% render_table issue_table "django_tables2/issue_table.html"%}
        {% if "change_issuelist" in issuelist_perms %}
            <form action="{% url 'srt.views.newissue' issuelist.id %}" method="get" class="add_issue">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Add Issue</button>
            </form>
        {% endif %}
    </div>
    {% if issue.id %}
        <div id="panel2" class="auto-style5">
            {% if "change_issuelist" in issuelist_perms %}
                <form action="{% url 'srt.views.editissue' issuelist.id issue.id %}" method="get" class="add_issue">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Edit Issue</button>
                </form>
            {% endif %}
            <strong>Title:</strong> <em>{{issue.title}}<br><br></em>
            {% if "delete_issuelist" in issuelist_perms %}
                <form action="{% url 'srt.views.deleteissue' issuelist.id issue.id %}" method="post" class="add_issue" onsubmit="return confirm('Do you really want to delete Issue with title: {{issue.title}}?');">{% csrf_token %}
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Delete Issue</button>
                </form>
            {% endif %}
            <strong>Summary: </strong><em>{{issue.summary}}<br><br></em>
            <strong>SSS Tracking Number:</strong><span style="padding-left:1.2em;">{{issue.sss_tracking}}</span><br><br>
            <strong>Cust. Tracking Number:</strong><span style="padding-left:0.2em">{{issue.customer_tracking}}</span><br>
            <strong><br>Suspected Component: </strong>{{issue.suspected_component}}<br><br>
            <strong>Status: </strong>{% inplace_edit "issue.status" %}<br><br>
            <strong>Completed Actions/Updates:<br></strong>
            {% render_table update_action_table "django_tables2/action_table.html"%}
            <br><strong>Next Steps/Action:</strong>
            {% if "change_issuelist" in issuelist_perms %}
                <form action="{% url 'srt.views.newaction' issuelist.id issue.id %}" method="get" class="add_new_action">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Add New Action</button>
                </form>
            {% endif %}
            {% render_table planned_action_table "django_tables2/action_table.html"%}
            <br><strong>Historic Actions/Updates:<br></strong>
            {% render_table historic_action_table "django_tables2/action_table.html"%}
        </div>

            {% if action.id %}
                <div id="panel3" class="auto-style4">

                    <form action="{% url 'srt.views.action_attachments' issuelist.id issue.id action.id %}" method="get" class="add_issue">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Attachments</button>
                    </form>

                    <strong>Action: </strong><em>{{ action.title }}</em><br><br>
                    <strong>Description: </strong><em>{{ action.description }}</em><br><br>
                    <strong>Current Action State: </strong>{% inplace_edit "action.state" %}<br>
                    <!-- <strong>Issue: </strong><em>{{issue.title}}</em><br><br> -->

                    {% if "delete_issuelist" in issuelist_perms %}
                        <br>
                        <form action="{% url 'srt.views.deleteaction' issuelist.id issue.id action.id %}" method="post" class="add_issue" onsubmit="return confirm('Do you really want to delete the Action with title: {{action.title}}?');">{% csrf_token %}
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Delete Action</button>
                        </form>
                    {% endif %}
                    {% if "delete_issuelist" in issuelist_perms %}
                        <form action="{% url 'srt.views.editaction' issuelist.id issue.id action.id %}" method="get" class="add_new_action">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Edit Action</button>
                        </form>          
                        <br>
                    {% endif %}

                    <br>
                    {% render_table actionlog_table "django_tables2/action_table.html"%}
                    {% if "change_issuelist" in issuelist_perms %}
                        <form action="{% url 'srt.views.newactionlog' issuelist.id issue.id action.id %}" method="get" class="add_action_log">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Add Action Log</button>
                        </form>
                    {% endif %}
                </div>
            {% endif %}
        {% endif %}
</div></section>
{% endblock %}
```

View for that template:

```
def view_issues(request, issuelist_id, issue_id=None, action_id=None):

issuelist = get_object_or_404(IssueList, id=issuelist_id)
issue_table = IssueTable(Issue.objects.filter(issuelist = issuelist).order_by("-added"), prefix="i")

if (issue_id is None) and (action_id is None):
    issue = []
    action = []
    completed_action_list = []
    planned_action_list = []
    historic_action_list = []
    actionlog_list = []

elif (issue_id is not None) and (action_id is None):
    issue = get_object_or_404(Issue, id=issue_id)
    action = []
    completed_action_list = Action.objects.filter(issue = issue).exclude(state = Action.STATUS.PLANNED).exclude (state = Action.STATUS.IN_PROGRESS).exclude(is_historic = True).order_by("-event_date")
    historic_action_list = Action.objects.filter(issue = issue).exclude(state = Action.STATUS.PLANNED).exclude (state = Action.STATUS.IN_PROGRESS).exclude(is_historic = False).order_by("-event_date")
    planned_action_list = Action.objects.filter(issue = issue).exclude(state = Action.STATUS.COMPLETED).exclude(state = Action.STATUS.ABANDONED).order_by("-event_date")
    actionlog_list = []

elif (issue_id is not None) and (action_id is not None):
    action = get_object_or_404(Action, id=action_id)
    issue = get_object_or_404(Issue, id=issue_id)
    completed_action_list = Action.objects.filter(issue = issue).exclude(state = Action.STATUS.PLANNED).exclude (state = Action.STATUS.IN_PROGRESS).exclude(is_historic = True).order_by("-event_date")
    historic_action_list = Action.objects.filter(issue = issue).exclude(state = Action.STATUS.PLANNED).exclude (state = Action.STATUS.IN_PROGRESS).exclude(is_historic = False).order_by("-event_date")
    planned_action_list = Action.objects.filter(issue = issue).exclude(state = Action.STATUS.COMPLETED).exclude(state = Action.STATUS.ABANDONED).order_by("-event_date")
    actionlog_list = ActionLog.objects.filter(action = action).order_by("-log_date")

else:
    return HttpResponseNotFound('<h1>Page not found</h1>')

update_action_table = CompletedActionTable(reversed(completed_action_list), prefix="u")
historic_action_table = CompletedActionTable(reversed(historic_action_list), prefix="h")
planned_action_table = PlannedActionTable(planned_action_list, prefix="p")    
if request.user.has_perm('srt.change_issuelist', issuelist):
    actionlog_table = ActionLogTable(actionlog_list, prefix="l")
else:
    actionlog_table = ActionLogTableUnEditable(actionlog_list, prefix="l")

RequestConfig(request, paginate={"per_page":20}).configure(issue_table)
RequestConfig(request, paginate=False).configure(update_action_table)
RequestConfig(request, paginate={"per_page":5}).configure(historic_action_table)
RequestConfig(request, paginate=False).configure(planned_action_table)
RequestConfig(request, paginate=False).configure(actionlog_table)    

return render(request, 'srt/view_issues.html', {
    'issuelist':issuelist , 
    'issue': issue, 
    'action': action, 
    'issue_table':issue_table, 
    'update_action_table': update_action_table, 
    'historic_action_table': historic_action_table, 
    'planned_action_table': planned_action_table, 
    'actionlog_table': actionlog_table
    })
```

Comment: I believe (you don't provide any additional details) that this should be handled by JS and if needed some ajax request.

Comment: I'm not very fluent with AJAX and  JS, could you direct me to some example / sample code and such? Also, I'll edit my question to show my view and my template.

Comment: Also, in the current form it looks very inefficient.

Comment: You are over filtering your model for something you could also achieve with a single query and some template filtration, secondly why don't you use Django class based views? it would save you a load of repeated code...
You could pass a FormView combined with ajax to load the response, or your could opt for a REST API for such kind of logic.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into Django class based views. Could you please explain more about the "You are over filtering your model for something you could also achieve with a single query and some template filtration" part? I'm not sure what exactly I am supposed to do. Thanks much for your time.